# nodejs refusing to connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am having issues setting up backend server. I ran to this error, how can I fix it?

```
conn.once('open', () => {
    console.log('DB Connected');
    gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection('images')
})
```

Terminal:

```
DB Connected
file:///home/user/Desktop/project/back-end/server.js:43
    gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
        ^

ReferenceError: gfs is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
conn.once('open', () => {
    console.log('DB Connected');
    // add 'const' before 'gfs'
    const gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection('images')
})
```